# Other Admins Editing my Task Scheduler Tasks

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2016

When I create a task in Windows Server 2016 Task Scheduler, it assigns authorship to me and looks like this:
[image]

Unfortunately, another admin named john_local is able to later change the User of the task to himself. Then, he can modify the Actions to do whatever he wants:
[image]

After john_local does this, I am still credited as the author of the task. I don't think this has happened to me in real life, but I don't want people taking good tasks I created and modifying them to do bad things in my name.

1. Is there a way in Windows Task scheduler to lock down a task such that **only** the author can modify it?
2. If not, is there a way to force task scheduler to reassign authorship whenever an admin alters another user's task?
3. Lastly, if none of the previous two options are possible, is there a way to keep a revision history of changes made to each task scheduler task?

To an extent, I suppose I can use signed PowerShell scripts to prevent tampering, but even with that, I'm concerned someone or something could still go into task manager and re-point **my** tasks at malicious script or exe files I have not authored. Careful audit logs would likely clear me, but an incident of this nature still might make me look bad.

Comment: Well if you have multiple admins on 1 machine you have to trust each other ...

Comment: depends whether you trust your fellow admins. You can set up auditing but then they can turn that off.

Comment: If this is your own personal machine, then reduce john's permissions, or remove them entirely. If it's corporate/educational, then just report it to whoever is in charge & wait for the dust to settle ;)